# What is Laguerre's definition of the angle via the cross ratio?

Tags: reference-request, geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, non-euclidean-geometry

I recently read an article which said Cayley showed that affine geometry could be developed from projective geometry after he learnt of Laguerre's definition of the angle using the cross ratio. This was then used by Klein to develop the Klein disk model of the hyperbolic plane which established the equiconsistency of Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry.

I've looked online for an exposition of this definition of Laguerre's but have found nothing. I've also looked into a textbook of Coxeter's on projective geometry and ahain come up with nothing peryaining to the above although Coxeter does give, he says, an improved definition of an angle, it relies on on Euclid's original definition.

Q. What is Laguerre's definition of the angle using the cross ratio?

Comment: Can you cite the reference where you read it? Maybe give an exact quotation?

Comment: Maybe you are referring to [Laguerre formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_formula)?

Comment: @user6530: I think that's likely to be it, thanks! If you want to note this in an answer, I can vote up and accept.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, thus comment. The relevant publications may be: [1] Edmond Laguerre-Verly, "Note sur la théorie des foyers." *Nouvelles annales de mathématiques: journal des candidats aux écoles polytechnique et normale,* Vol. 12, 1853, [pp. 57-66](http://www.numdam.org/item/NAM_1853_1_12__57_0.pdf). [2] Arthur Cayley, "A Sixth Memoir upon Quantics." *Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London*, Vol. 149, Dec. 1859, [pp. 61-90](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/epdf/10.1098/rstl.1859.0004) ....

Comment: .... [3] Felix Klein, "Ueber die sogenannte Nicht-Euklidische Geometrie." 
*Mathematische Annalen*, Vol. 4, No. 4, Dec. 1871, [pp. 573-625](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0004?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B586%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D)

Comment: Laguerre's paper as scanned by Google [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nouvelles_annales_de_math%C3%A9matiques/gQUTAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA57&printsec=frontcover)